# error message "The text is too long to be edited" in Expression Builder for a Control Source

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-reports

Try to put the following in the main report to sum the totals from three sub reports:

```
=IIf(IsNull([FCR_LABOR_COST subreport].[Report]![Total_Labor_Cost]),0,[FCR_LABOR_COST subreport].[Report]![Total_Labor_Cost])
+IIf(IsNull([FCR_EXPENSES subreport].[Report]![Total_Expenses]),0,[FCR_EXPENSES subreport].[Report]![Total_Expenses])
+IIf(IsNull([FCR_EQUIPMENT subreport].[Report]![Total_Equipment]),0,[FCR_EQUIPMENT subreport].[Report]![Total_Eqipment])
```

Received the following error message:

> The text is too long to be edit.

How do I resolve this? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it using [`Nz`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) expressions to achieve the same result -

```
=Nz([FCR_LABOR_COST subreport].[Report]![Total_Labor_Cost], 0) +
 Nz([FCR_EXPENSES subreport].[Report]![Total_Expenses], 0) +
 Nz([FCR_EQUIPMENT subreport].[Report]![Total_Equipment], 0)
```